# Converting char arrays into values and put into int array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to pass the position of a string array as an argument for an int array and I'm getting invalid indirection  as an error. I wanted to count the frequencies of the pokemons i've caught when they are randomly generated and caught. I've done a fair bit of research and still couldn't grasp the concept of it. P.S. my lecturer is teaching outdated versions of C so mind the printf(s).

```
int encounter() {
  //list of pokemons
  char pokemon[5][10] = {"Magikarp", "Zubat", "Eevee", "Magmar", "Pikachu"};
  int type[5] = {0,0,0,0,0};
  int i;
  int a=0;
  //random number generator from 0 - 4
  srand(time(NULL));
  i = (rand() % 5);

  //prints out the pokemon name 
  printf("A wild %s appeared! \n", pokemon[i]);

  type[pokemon[i]] += 1;

  for(a=0; a<6; a++) {
    printf(type[a]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "***my lecturer is teaching outdated versions of C so mind the printf(s).***" what does that mean?

Comment: The version of C you’re using can’t be that outdated: you’re using inline comments, which weren’t in the standard until C99.

Comment: The problem of indirection is here `type[pokemon[i]] += 1;`. Replace that code by simply `type[i] += 1;`, because, pokemon[i] is an array of char.

Comment: Are you perhaps thinking of `cout` in C++? C uses `printf`.

Comment: Why print a space character immediately before a newline?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I've heard from my lecturer that in C we don't use printf(s) anymore ?

Comment: No, we still use `printf` in C. You wouldn’t generally use them in C++. Not sure why your lecturer would say that...

Comment: The C FAQ is an indispensable resource. See http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html and http://c-faq.com/charstring/index.html

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
type[pokemon[i]] += 1;
```

is incorrect.

`pokemon[i]` has type `char*`; i.e. it is a pointer, and should not be used to index the `type` array.  I think you meant to index the `type` array with `i`.  It should be

```
type[i] += 1;
```

Also, the loop that prints the types is wrong.  It iterates 6 times, but the `type` array has only 5 elements (`0..4` inclusive).  Finally, the `printf` function wants a format string as the first argument (it has since the beginning of time), so it should be:

```
for(a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
    printf("%d\n", type[a]);
}
```

Comment: I was unaware that pokemon[i] was a pointer, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

1. With the line `type[pokemon[i]] += 1;` you are trying to pass a string as the index of an array.  What you should be doing is `type[i]`.
2. `for(a=0; a<6; a++)` will go out of bounds since `type` has five elements, not six.
3. `printf(type[a])` is not valid C; `printf` can only print an integer if it is passed a valid *format string* specifying an integer.  Try `printf("%d\n", type[a]);`

Answer (score -1):

In your example `i` stands for generated pockemon index. If it is randomly generated i.e. it takes value of 3, it refers to pockemon called "Magmar" (`pockemon[3]`). The type array holds number of caught pokemons, so that it has to be indexed by the pockemon index itself and not by position of string array which does not make sense.

correct `type[pokemon[i]] += 1;`
to `type[[i]] += 1;`